# C# UDPClient not receiving packets over external IP

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sockets, unity-game-engine, udp

So here's the thing, i'm creating a server/client environment for a game where a port forwarded computer acts as a server, and clients send the first UDP message to connect and get the accept message then start sending the in-game UDP messages after successfully connecting.
The problem is, when I use the local IPs say the server using 10.0.0.7 and a client is using 10.0.0.4, everything works just fine:

1. Client sends connect message.
2. Server receives it.
3. Servers sends back accept message.
4. Client receives it
5. All further messages reach both ends without any problem.

But when I use the external IP:

1. Client sends connect message.
2. Server receives it.
3. Servers sends back accept message.
4. Client receives it
5. Both ends can send messages but the client doesn't receive any more messages.

Wanted to know at the end if the problem is somehow from the code, or from what I think it's really from, router, NAT, firewalls or anything like that.
(Note: Client sends to server's 8888 port, and server sends back through the client's local port, as it should be.)

Below is the client code, written for Unity:

```
void Start()
{
    client = new UdpClient();
    client.Connect(IPAddress.Parse("<Global IP>"), 8888);
    client.BeginReceive(new AsyncCallback(ReadMessage), client);
}

private void ReadMessage(IAsyncResult result)
{
    IPEndPoint ipEndPoint = null;
    string message = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(client.EndReceive(result, ref ipEndPoint));
    print("Got: " + message);
    string[] wholeMessages = message.Split('#');
    for (int w = 0; w < wholeMessages.Length - 1; w++)
    {


        string[] parts = wholeMessages[w].Split('$');
        if (!connected && parts.Length == 3 && parts[0] == "accept" && int.TryParse(parts[1], out ID))
        {
            connected = true;
            code = parts[2];
        }
    }
    client.BeginReceive(new AsyncCallback(ReadMessage), client);
}

public void SendUDP(string message)
{
    client.Send(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message), message.Length);
}
```

Comment: Could you add the server code too?

Comment: I'm still learning about the message structure and splitting and such..
https://pastebin.com/AAgz5Nun

it works on localhost, and inside LAN (10.0.0.5, 10.0.0.1) but not on global IP, on global IP it receives only first message, though tried checking stuff on Wireshark and the computer got them, but not the application.

Comment: It's for a Unity game btw..

Comment: On your client, instead of using IPAddress.Parse, what happens if you go

IPAddress[] ip = Dns.GetHostAddresses(ipAddress);
client.Connect(ip[0], 8888);

also try looping through the ip array and printing what it returns

Comment: Got only one IP, the same IP.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after several trials and errors this worked for me...

//Server Code

```
    private static UdpClient udpClient;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Server initiated...");
        udpClient = new UdpClient(8888);
    }

    private static void ReadMessage()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                IPEndPoint IPEP = null;
                string message = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(udpClient.Receive(ref IPEP));
            }
        }
    }
    private static void SendUDP(IPEndPoint e,string message)
    {
        new UdpClient().Send(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message), message.Length, e);
    }
```

//Client Code

```
private IPAddress ip;

void Start()
{
    ip = Dns.GetHostAddresses("HOSTNAME")[0];
    client = new UdpClient(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0));
    udpThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ReadMessage))
    {
        IsBackground = true  
    };
    udpThread.Start();
}

private void ReadMessage()
{
    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            IPEndPoint IPEP = null;
            byte[] data = client.Receive(ref IPEP);
            string message = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data);
        }
    }
}
public void SendUDP(string message)
{
    client.Send(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message), message.Length, new IPEndPoint(ip, 8888));
}
```